# Find out which office.js requirement set my code is using

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I would like to integrate into my CI/CD pipeline a requirement set condition.

I'm developing an Office.js Excel addin and I would like to track client compatibility.
There is a way to inspect code to detect the maximum value of requirement set?

The codebase is not so small, and I want to keep an eye on client compatibility.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Good question! There is no tools for such tasks, developers are responsible for checking the requirement set before using a particular method or property in the code of Office add-ins.

Sounds like a subject for a feature suggestion. You can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.

Comment: Thanks fo addressing me on Tech Community. I have Submitted a suggestion on [this post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/find-out-which-office-js-requirement-set-my-code-is-using/idi-p/3677366#M1474). If the suggestion is valuable in your opinion, upvote is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, definitely. I'd love to have something like that for my solutions.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no automated way to see what Req Sets are used by your code. That would be a valuable tool. Consider suggesting it at [Microsoft 365 Developer Platform Ideas](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform).

Comment: Thanks fo addressing me on Developer Platfom Ideas. I have Submitted an idea on [this post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/find-out-which-office-js-requirement-set-my-code-is-using/idi-p/3677366#M1474). If the suggestion is valuable in your opinion, upvote and further discussions are appreciated.